# Categorize results coming from a Lucene index

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a Lucene index, generated through Hibernate with the help of Hibernate Search annotations, with 3 fields (just to simplify a bit) that describe an article:

`id, title, brand`

An example of content:

`id, title, brand
 1, "Long skirt", "Sweet and Gabbana"
 2, "Sweet neck vest", "Armani"
 3, "Sweet feeling shirt", "Armani"`

Notice how "Sweet and Gabbana", "Sweet neck vest" and "Sweet feeling shirt" share the word "sweet".

I would like to make a Lucene query so that, if I search for the keyword "sweet", I get 2 distinct categories, one for titles and the other one for brands. Eg:

- Titles -> "Sweet neck vest", "Sweet feeling shirt"
- Brands -> "Sweet and Gabbana"

In other words I want to show to users that the system founds results among these 2 different categories.

When I run the query (a sort of OR between titles and brands) I get the all three entries (in Lucene, the documents with ids 1, 2, and 3) that contain exclusively one attribute or the other one, but how do I categorize them ?

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

...

@Override
public List<ArticleByIndexModel> retrieveArticlesSearchQueryResult(final String searchString,
        final String languageIso639) {

    final FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
    final org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = buildUpArticlesSearchLuceneQuery(searchString,
            languageIso639, fullTextEntityManager);

    final String titleFieldName = ArticleTranslationFieldPrefixes.TITLE + languageIso639;
    final String brandNameFieldName = BrandTaxonomy.BrandTaxonomyNameFieldName.NAME;

    final FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery);
    fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(50);
    fullTextQuery.setProjection(Article_.articleID.getName(), titleFieldName, brandNameFieldName,
            Article_.brandSku.getName(), FullTextQuery.DOCUMENT_ID, FullTextQuery.EXPLANATION, FullTextQuery.THIS);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) fullTextQuery.getResultList();

    final List<ArticleByIndexModel> resultList = list.stream()
            .map(x -> new ArticleByIndexModel((Integer) x[0], (String) x[1])).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return resultList;
}

private org.apache.lucene.search.Query buildUpArticlesSearchLuceneQuery(final String searchString,
        final String languageIso639, final FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager) {

    final String brandSkuName = Article_.brandSku.getName();

    final String analyzerPartName = ArticleTranslationDiscriminator.getAnalyzerPartNameByLanguage(languageIso639);
    final String titleFieldName = ArticleTranslationFieldPrefixes.TITLE + languageIso639;
    final String titleEdgeNGramFieldName = ArticleTranslationFieldPrefixes.TITLE_EDGE_N_GRAM + languageIso639;
    final String titleNGramFieldName = ArticleTranslationFieldPrefixes.TITLE_N_GRAM + languageIso639;

    final String brandNameEdgeNGramFieldName = BrandTaxonomy.BrandTaxonomyNameFieldName.NAME_EDGE_N_GRAM;
    final String brandNameNGramFieldName = BrandTaxonomy.BrandTaxonomyNameFieldName.NAME_N_GRAM;

    final SearchFactory searchFactory = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory();
    final QueryBuilder qb = searchFactory.buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Article.class)
            .overridesForField(titleFieldName, ArticleTranslationFieldPrefixes.TITLE + analyzerPartName)
            .overridesForField(titleEdgeNGramFieldName,
                    ArticleTranslationFieldPrefixes.TITLE_EDGE_N_GRAM + analyzerPartName)
            .overridesForField(titleNGramFieldName, ArticleTranslationFieldPrefixes.TITLE_N_GRAM + analyzerPartName)
            .get();

    final org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery =
            /**/
            qb.bool()
                    /**/
                    .should(qb.phrase().withSlop(2).onField(titleNGramFieldName).andField(titleEdgeNGramFieldName)
                            .boostedTo(5).sentence(searchString.toLowerCase()).createQuery())
                    /**/
                    .should(qb.phrase().withSlop(2).onField(brandNameNGramFieldName)
                            .andField(brandNameEdgeNGramFieldName).boostedTo(5).sentence(searchString.toLowerCase())
                            .createQuery())
                    /**/
                    .should(qb.keyword().onField(brandSkuName).matching(searchString.toLowerCase()).createQuery())
                    /**/
                    .createQuery();

    return luceneQuery;
}
```

I see no solutions in making 2 different queries and then merging the results.

I read about the Facets but I do not think they are appropriate in this case.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Why not make just one query, then traverse the results and create the categories yourself? I think that even if lucene had something of this sort (some sort of grouping), it would do just that...

Comment: Unrelated note: you probably don't want to project on `FullTextQuery.DOCUMENT_ID`, since this is an internal ID and is not the same as your entity ID. Use `FullTextQuery.ID` instead.

Comment: @Yossy, I can't do as you suggested because the query I reported in the question returns back all documents and then there is no way to group the result by categories (unless I use some sort of pattern matching on results).
Yoann. Yes, I know. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need to show the results to the user as a single list with some description for each item (matched because of title/matched because of brand/both).

I don't think there's a feature that would allow you to do *exactly* that in Hibernate Search. I guess there would be some way to do it using low-level Lucene APIs (Collectors), but this would involve some dark magic and I don't think we would be able to plug that in Hibernate Search.

So let's go the easier path: do it yourself.

Personally I would simply run multiple queries:

- the first time just as you do in your example
- the second time projecting on the IDs (`.setProjection(ProjectionContants.ID)`) and using only two clauses: one mandating that matches have the same ID as one of the results of the first query (basically `must(should(id=<firstID>), should(id=<secondID>), ... )`, and one mandating that the search string matches on the title (basically `must(title=<searchString>)`
- the third time similar to the second, but with the brand instead of the title

Then I'd use the result of the second and third query to determine whether a given result matched because of the title or because of the brand.

Of course that will only work if the search string is only expected to fully match either the title or the brand (or both), not if some part of the search string matches the title, and some other part matches the brand. But if that's what you want, your current query is wrong anyway...

Comment: @Yoann.You've understood my problem perfectly and I fully share your idea of ​​multiple queries to get what I'm looking for in the index. Thanks!!